# Using ghostcript from R

Tags: r, ghostscript

I am trying to call ghostcript from R to crop pdf files, but cannot make it work.
The ghostscript code is working fine when used in a command prompt. The reason for using R and not directly Ghostscrip is that I have to deal with many pdfs that are created from a loop within R.

The code is:

```
argument<-c("C:\\gs9.06\\bin\\gswin32.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o C:\\cropped.pdf -c [/CropBox [0.3 12.5 116.2 169] /PAGES pdfmark -f C:\\uncropped.pdf")
system2(command="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe", args=argument)
```

R returns:

```
'ropBox' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning message:
running command '"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" "C:\\gs9.06\\bin\\gswin32.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o J:\\Mapinfo\\cropped.pdf -c [/CropBox [0.3 12.5 116.2 169] /PAGES pdfmark -f J:\\Mapinfo\\testing.pdf"' had status 1
```

It seems that R does not like the "/" sign, but I do not know how to fix this.
Any suggestion?

-Vincent

Comment: I could be missing something, but why don't you just run the `gswin32` program through a `system2` call (the console version is `GSWIN32C.EXE` by the way) and pass the arguments to that program in `args=`? I'm not sure why `cmd` is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to rearrange your call a bit.

```
system2("C:\\program.exe",args="-program arguments")
```

I can't test this on my current machine (run at your own risk), but I think in your instance it would look like:

```
system2("C:\\gs9.06\\bin\\gswin32c.exe",args="-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o C:\\cropped.pdf -c [/CropBox [0.3 12.5 116.2 169] /PAGES pdfmark -f C:\\uncropped.pdf")
```

Comment: And it was a simple as that: the above code works perfectly. Cheers!

Comment: @VincentZintzen - No problems - if this solved the issue, please tick the green arrow next to this answer so that others know this solved the problem.